# XML strings in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I have a JPA entity class mimicking a table. Something like this:

```
@XmlType(name="MyClassElementType")
public class MyClass {
    String name;
    String xmlDesc;

    public MyClass() {}

    @XmlElement
    String getName() { return name; }
    void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @XmlElement
    String getXmlDesc() { return xmlDesc; }
    void setXmlDesc(String xmlDesc) { this.xmlDesc = xmlDesc; }
}
```

In a Jersey REST get call I'm trying to return this class:

```
@Get
@Produces("application/xml")
public MyClass get() {

    return myClass;
}
```

Now I'm expecting the already xml string(xmlStr) to be returned as is, but Jersey/JAXB escapes it...

So anyway around this?

Answer (score 3):

JAXB has no way of knowing that `xmlDesc` contains an XML string, it could be anything, so it *has* to escape it.

If you want to store arbitrary XML in a JAXB object model, you need to store it as an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element`. JAXB should then convert that to/from XML as necessary.

Comment: @OOO: You'll need to use `@XmlAnyElement` rather than `@XmlElement`